# Multi Linear Regression Plotting Error: X and Y must be the same size

Tags: python, linear-regression, data-science, data-analysis

I have a dataset, a 100x3, all have values. I'm having trouble in plotting my model. In keeps saying that x and Y must be of the same size. However, when I use

```
if len(x1) == len(y):
  print('Equal')
else:
  print('Not Equal')
```

it gives me equal.

here is my code for plotting

```
plt.scatter(x1,y)
yhat = 227.7009*x1 + -5.772e+06
fig = plt.plot(x1,yhat, lw=1, c='blue' , label = 'regression line')
plt.xlabel('size',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('price',fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

EDIT: would also like to ask if I'm missing something on my code,

```
#import the necessary packages that we need.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import seaborn
seaborn.set()
data = pd.read_csv('real_estate_price_size_year.csv')
data
data.describe()
#our dependent variable would be the GPA.
y = data['price']
#and our predictor would be the SAT Score.
x1 = data[['size','year']]
x = sm.add_constant(x1)
results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
results.summary()
plt.scatter(x1,y)
yhat = 227.7009 * x1 + -5.772e+06
fig = plt.plot(x1,yhat, lw=1, c='blue' , label = 'regression line')
plt.xlabel('size',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('price',fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: pls give output type(x1) and type(y). I suppose that it numpy array. if so, give output x1.shape and y.shape